# Failing js test - spy was never called

Tags: reactjs

In the following test I am gettingthe error:

Error: spy was not called with [[studentId:0]]

Can anyone please tell me where the studentId is coming from and why I'm get the error?

```
describe('<EditStudentDocuments />', () => {

var updateStudentDataSpy = expect.createSpy();

beforeEach(() => {
    mockery.enable();
});

afterEach(() => {
    mockery.disable();
});

it('should render EditStudentDocumentsTable', () => {
    var wrapper = shallow(<EditStudentDocuments />);
    expect(wrapper.find(EditStudentDocumentsTable).length).toBe(1);
});

it('should render EditStudentDocumentsTable 2', () => {
    var updateStudentDataSpy = expect.createSpy();
    var mockStudentDataActions = {
        updateStudentData: updateStudentDataSpy
    };
    mockery.registerMock('../../../actions/studentDataActions', mockStudentDataActions);

    const myRow = { };
    const data = { row : myRow, type: "myType" };
    var wrapper = shallow(<EditStudentDocuments />);
    wrapper.find(EditStudentDocumentsTable).props().onTableUpdate(data);
    expect(updateStudentDataSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(myRow);
});
```

Comment: It's originating from your last line `expect(updateStudentDataSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(myRow);`. I'm not familiar with mockery, but you aren't passing in any props (which I would assume is where the action you are trying to call resides).